# Confused on why I am getting a syntax error when writing my where clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to create two queries. In the first query I must select all the rows in Illinois, Indiana, Wisconsin, and Michigan. I am confused on why I am getting a syntax error when I try to write my select statement. Dealerships is the table being referenced. Can anyone please help?

```
select *
from dealerships
where state = 'IL','IN', 'WI', 'MI'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column can't simultaneously equal four different values.  You're looking for the `IN` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM dealerships WHERE state IN ('IL','IN','WI','MI')
```

If you were to write this much more verbosely to specifically use the `=` operator (just for demonstration purposes), it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM dealerships WHERE state = 'IL'
  OR state = 'IN'
  OR state = 'WI'
  OR state = 'MI'
```